# Very simple Sitemap in Sitecore

Tags: razor, sitecore

I have this rather simple Sitemap in a Sitecore solution using Razor;

```
@{
        var root = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(myRootId);
        <div class="sitemap">
            @RecursiveSitemap(root)
        </div>    
    }

    @helper RecursiveSitemap(Item parentItem){
        <ul>
        @{
            Sitecore.Collections.ChildList childList = parentItem.Children;
            foreach (Item child in childList)
            {
                <li><a href="@Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(child)">@child["title"]</a></li>
                if (child.Children.Count != 0)
                {
                    RecursiveSitemap(child);
                }
            }
        }
        </ul> 
    }
```

It returns the first level as expected, but no more. I cannot figure out why - what am i missing?

Comment: Try to debug your code, see what it does.

Comment: The debugger returns the results - but still dont know what is wrong with the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the @ to the second call to `RecursiveSitemap(child)` so it won't write out the result.

It must be:

```
if (child.Children.Count != 0)
{
  @RecursiveSitemap(child);
}
```